# Which slide out panel is compatible with bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to use this slide out panel with Bootstrap, which give you the option to slide out from the right http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html  . but it doesnt seem compatible. can someone recommend which slide out panel I can use that is compatible with bootstrap?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A bit of CSS and jQuery are enough to rebuild this function. Take a look at my jsfiddle.

jQuery Snippet

```
    $('#opener').on('click', function() {       
    var panel = $('#slide-panel');
    if (panel.hasClass("visible")) {
        panel.removeClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'-300px'});
    } else {
        panel.addClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'0px'});
    }   
    return false;   
});
```

Full Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9Le8X/2/

Comment: Thank you..how do i go about adding it to the right side. so that when the screen resizes it always stay at the right?

Comment: Yes. how can i remove the horizontal scrolling ?

Comment: body {overflow-x: hidden;}